# DropDown menu that when chosen turns option into a button

Tags: javascript, php, html

does anyone know if there is a way to make a dropdown menu that when an option is chosen it then turns that option into a button using html or is that only possible in php or is it not possible at all

Comment: What you really want? When an option is selected you want to perform some function. Is that you required?

Comment: @James McPhee upvote or accept any answer which you feel it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this its working

**Html**

```
<input type="button" id="conv_but" value="" style="display:none">
    <select name="data_select" id="data_select" onchange="converttobutton(this.value);">
        <option value="One">One</option>
        <option value="Two">Two</option>
        <option value="Three">Three</option>
        <option value="Four">Four</option>
        <option value="Five">Five</option>
        <option value="Six">Six</option>
    </select>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function converttobutton(selected)
    {
        document.getElementById('conv_but').value = selected;
        document.getElementById('data_select').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('conv_but').style.display = '';
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to learn javascript to be able to do that, there is an event fired called `onselect`, when you bind to that event with javascript using `addEventListener` you will be able to read the `.value` of the `<select>` field and then create a button using the `createElement` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sel_html = $('#element_place').html();
    $('#select_button').change(function(){
        var sel_option = $('#select_button').val();
        $('#select_button').remove();
        new_ele = $('<input>').attr('type','button').attr('value',sel_option);
        $('#element_place').append(new_ele);
    });
});
</script>
<div id="element_place">
<select id="select_button">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `change()` event handler . Create a function inside the `change()` event for creating the button

```
$("ID of the dropdownbox").change (function () { 

//code for creating button(this.value) give the selected option

 var $something= $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'button', 
  name:'btn1', value:this.value});
 //append this variable inside a div having ID  `button_div`
  $("#button_div").append($something);
 });
```

Comment: @James McPhee the idea given by Veerendra is better option than my answer.